# Seem to be having a problem with RealVNC with centos can't input username

Tags: linux, centos, users, vnc

Hello I seem to be having a problem with RealVNC with centos. I want to connect to  a another machine, but can't because it has been "grayed out". In otherwords, I can't type in the username in the username field and can only type in the password.

My VNC viewer version is 4.1. I've installed it from the add software section from centos.

Answer (score 1):

This is a normal configuration for VNC.  Normally, VNC is already running as a user and the VNC password is being prompted for.  This is often different than the user's password.

It is possible to configure VNC to start from `xinetd` and use a desktop manager like `xdm` to handle logins.  I documented my Ubuntu solutions for [Remote Desktops with VNC and RDP](http://www.systemajik.com/blog/remote-desktops-with-vnc-and-rdp/).